# How to fix distortion on this dual stage amplifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt

[image: My amplifier with its output currently]

I think I am at a point where my gain is where I want it, but I am currently experiencing distortion on the Vout when V<0.  What needs to change to remedy this?

Comment: What are the waveforms shown in the picture representing i.e. what nodes. Also what unexpected distortion are you seeing that I'm not?

Comment: The upper half of the waveform is significantly higher than the bottom half. The red is my Vout, the white is my Vin.

Comment: Yes, that happens when you have emitter capacitors. Asymmetrical distortion is unavoidable. Your circuit is not a good design for 500 MHz especially if it's driving into a 50 ohm load.

Comment: Is there a fix regarding that you'd suggest? I am able to change the 50 ohm value for RE3 if necessary.

Comment: No, you need a much more serious design approach when 500 MHz and 50 ohm loading is required (as I suspect it will be). So, if this was an audio amplifier you could have an extra resistor as you implemented in the first stage but, because of the other reasons, this type of circuit is largely inappropriate.

Comment: 50 ohm loading is not required in this circuit, the 50 ohm load is used for output impedance, however, I am planning to replace it with a matching network instead.

Comment: @Chief Are you familiar with feedback amplifier design? They use two forms of NFB and often just a single BJT to obtain the kind of wide bandwidth, controlled gain, and controlled/stable input and output resistances that you are talking about. Also, specific construction techniques are usually required. Practical feedback amplifier circuits of this type don't look much like what you illustrate. So I'm guessing 'not so much.' But that's for you to say.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've got Q2 pretty well into saturation.  The base is held at 2.86VDC by your bias resistors RB1 and RB2, meaning the emitter is at about 2.26V.  The current that generates 2.26V across 50 ohms generates 22.6V across 500 ohms, well in excess of the 10V available.  That's also why you have nowhere near the >100 gain you were designing for.

Also, at half a GHz, that 47uF cap has little effect (if simulated realistically) or nearly a dead short (if modeled as an ideal cap), so that's something to look at too.

Comment: So would you suggest increasing the values of the base resistors for Q1? And for the 47uF cap, would you suggest increasing or decreasing the value?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to type, "would you suggest increasing the values of the resistors for RB1 and RB2?"

Comment: Now you're getting to the area where I'd need to know your specs/design goals for this circuit.  What frequency range does it need to cover?  How much gain do you need?  What sizes/geometries of parts do you intend to target?  What's your input signal range?

Comment: The specs for this circuit are the input and output Z should be 50 ohms, operating at 500MHz, with a 100MHz BW, with a minimum 6dB gain. Ideally current consumption should be below 50mA

Comment: In that case, it's unclear why you designed the first stage for 20dB gain and the second for a fairly arbitrary amount, or why you're using bypass caps in the uF range rather than the pF range.  You should edit your design goals and the decisions behind your choices of components into the question to make it more complete.  Include the amplitude range of the input signal and the geometries (chip parts will be less problematic than leaded ones at 0.5GHz, but I don't know your environment).

Comment: FYI, electrolytics don't disappear at high frequency; while ESL dominates at modest frequencies (say 10s MHz), absorption and transmission line effects probably take over up there. A ceramic chip will definitely be more predictable though.

Answer (score 2):

Your transistor has no part number and no specs. The frequency is much too high for the circuit to show any of its severe saturation distortion harmonics.
I added a 2N3904 transistor, reduced the microwave frequency to an RF frequency,
correctly biased the transistor for symmetrical clipping and reduced the input level to avoid clipping distortion.

Your specs for the circuit came too late for me to change everything.
[image: transistor biasing]